# Add logging to tests results in jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, jython, nose

I am using nose in jenkins to test a project. If a test fails, I get a short report of the output to the console. I would like to have this output regardless of the test result. So even if the test passes I want to be able to see the tests output to stderr/stdout.

At the moment I can turn off logging by calling nose with `--nocapture`. However this results in all the output beeing under the projects console log that jenkins creates by default. How I tell nose/capture to append the captured output to each test result shown in Jenkins?
I use `xunit` to generate a `junit` compatible `xml` file which is in turn used by Jenkins to generate its reports.

**edit:** Additional Infos as requested

Url in Jenkins (after buildnumber part):

`/testReport/testDesignParser.testDesignCsvParser.testDesignCsvParser/testDesignCsvParser/test/?`

I know that this design is not pretty but thats how it is now. If it matters:

```
`testDesignParser.testDesignCsvParser.testDesignCsvParser` module  
`testDesignCsvParser`                                      class  
`test`                                                     (member)testfunction
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense. How do you add output to a test case? Test cases are Python code and saying "add captured output to Python code" doesn't make sense.

Comment: Jenkins shows you a short report of the results, in case of failure the console output is in this report, I would like this output to be included as well in case the test succeeds. To bridge between Jenkins and nose I use `xunit` to generate a junit like testfile

Comment: Which Jenkins report do you refer to? Please tell us the URL after the project name (i.e. `/lastBuild/testReport/`)

Comment: `/testReport/testDesignParser.testDesignCsvParser.testDesignCsvParser/testDesignCsvParser/test/?` I know that this design is not pretty but thats how it is now. If it matters: `testDesignParser.testDesignCsvParser.testDesignCsvParser` **module**; `testDesignCsvParser` **class**, `test` **(member)testfunction**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the latest Jenkins there is an option to save the output (Retain long standard output/error) right under the post build step belonging to `JUnit`. Additionally I run nose with `--nocapture`. This gives me a console output view on every test (an option on the left menu when I have a test opened)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to achieve this from your tests. The report generator simply won't display the output unless there are errors.

You will have to get the sources for Jenkins itself (the JUnit runner is built into it) and patch the reporter or write your own plugin.

Comment: this is disappointing...   I though it was related to the fact that noses capture eats up everything, not to jenkins. I have to let this sit for a second before I mark that as accepted, +1 for now.

Comment: I don't see output for successful JUnit tests in Java, either. So you'd need to patch both (nose and Jenkins). Or file a feature request; being able to see the output of successful tests shouldn't be hard to implement and it might be handy.